# How to find a property of one object by matching a different property to another object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two objects in a d3 construct:

```
const visitors = [
              {
                 name: "polygon 1",
                 total: 342,
                 color: "red"
              },
              {
                 name: "polygon 2",
                 total: 342,
                 color: "blue"
              },
              {
                 name: "polygon 3",
                 total: 342,
                 color: "green"
              }
            ]

const polys = [{
                 name: "polygon 1",
                 points:[
                    {"x":-25, "y":48},
                    {"x":3,"y":48},
                    {"x":3,"y":40},
                    {"x":-25,"y":40},
                    {"x":-25,"y":48}
                  ]
               },
               {
                  name: "polygon 2",
                  points:[
                      {"x":5, "y":40},
                      {"x":23,"y":40},
                      {"x":23,"y":18},
                      {"x":5,"y":18},
                      {"x":5, "y":40}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "polygon 3",
                    points:[
                      {"x":-25, "y":40},
                      {"x":5,"y":40},
                      {"x":5,"y":34},
                      {"x":-25,"y":34},
                      {"x":-25, "y":40}
                    ]
               }]
```

Given the name of the polygon from the 'polys' object I need to find the color for that polygon from the 'visitors' object.

I've tried:

```
d = one object of the 'polys' obj

.attr("fill", function(d, visitors) {
    for(var key in d){
        if (key === 'name' && d.name === visitors.name){
            return visitors.color;
        }
    }
});
```

I have no problem returning the color if it was in the 'polys' object which defines the polygon, but the 'polys' object will essentially be static and the 'visitors' object will be dynamic and the color will change based on the number of visitors. How do I return the color from the 'visitors' object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got the answer from chatGPT:

```
// Select your polygons and set the fill color based on the 'visitors' data
d3.select("your-polygon-selector")
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        const name = d.name; // Get the name of the current polygon
        // Find the corresponding visitor object based on the polygon name
        const visitor = visitors.find(visitor => visitor.name === name);
        if (visitor) {
            return visitor.color; // Set the fill color from the visitor object
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the visitor data is not found for the polygon
            return "default-color"; // You can set a default color here
        }
    });
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate through the visitors array and check each `name` value against the polygon `name` value. If there is a match return that visitors color:

```
.attr("fill", function(d, visitors) {
    for(var x=0; x<visitors.length; x++){
        if(d.name == visitors[x].name){
            return visitors[x].color;
        }
    }
});
```

An alternative to the above is to map the visitor names to an array and then use `indexOf` to find the key:

```
.attr("fill", function(d, visitors) {
    var names = visitors.map(item => item.name);

    var x = names.indexOf( d.name );

    if( x > -1 ){
        return visitors[x].color;
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle I setup for testing - https://jsfiddle.net/p6sockau/

Comment: @'Samuel Cook' although it seems they should, neither of the suggestions worked. The second one gave the error "visitor.map is not a function"

Comment: `"visitor.map is not a function"` would indicate that `visitors` is not an array as described in your question. I'd start there to ensure that you're passing a valid array.

Comment: Also, you stated `visitor` in the comment and not `visitors`.

Comment: 'visitor' is a typo in my comment, but wasn't in my code. Also visitors is an array as can be seen in my code in the original question.